# Reorder Table Rows and columns Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 5x5 table:

```
  a  b  c  d  e
a 1  2  3  4  5
b 3  5  7  2  6
c 1  3  4  6  1
d 4  4  1  7  8
e 6  7  2  1  6
```

where the headers are the strings.
I want to know how to reorder the table rows and columns using the headers
so for example of I wanted them to be in this order `e b c a d` then this will be the table:

```
  e  b  c  a  d
e 6  7  2  6  1
b 6  5  7  3  2
c 1  3  4  1  6
a 5  7  3  1  4
d 8  4  1  4  7
```

Comment: By 'table', do you mean a 'matrix'?

Comment: nope, I mean a `table`. I'm checking the posted answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using indexing. You can indeed re-arrange the rows and columns using indices as you would for any array. In this case, I substitute each letter in the `headers` array with a number (originally `[1 2 3 4 5]`) and then, using a vector defining the new order `[5 2 3 1 4]`, re-order the table. You could make some kind of lookup table to automate this when you deal with larger tables:

```
clc
clear


a = [1  2  3  4  5;
 3  5  7  2  6;
 1  3  4  6  1;
 4  4  1  7  8;
 6  7  2  1  6];

headers = {'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'};

%// Original order. Not used but useful to understand the idea... I think :)
OriginalOrder = 1:5;

%// New order
NewOrder = [5 2 3 1 4];

%// Create table
t = table(a(:,1),a(:,2),a(:,3),a(:,4),a(:,5),'RowNames',headers,'VariableNames',headers)
```

As a less cumbersome alternative to manually creating the table with the function `table`, you can use (thanks to @excaza) the function `array2table` which saves a couple steps:

```
t = array2table(a,'RowNames',headers,'VariableNames',headers)
```

Either way, re-arrange the table using the new indices:

```
New_t = t(NewOrder,NewOrder)
```

Output:

```
t = 

         a    b    c    d    e
         _    _    _    _    _

    a    1    2    3    4    5
    b    3    5    7    2    6
    c    1    3    4    6    1
    d    4    4    1    7    8
    e    6    7    2    1    6


New_t = 

         e    b    c    a    d
         _    _    _    _    _

    e    6    7    2    6    1
    b    6    5    7    3    2
    c    1    3    4    1    6
    a    5    2    3    1    4
    d    8    4    1    4    7
```

Comment: You can use `array2table(a,'RowNames',headers,'VariableNames',headers)` rather than `table` to save yourself a little bit of typing.

Comment: thanks for the tip @excaza. If you don't mind I'll include it in the answer?

Comment: @excaza there is no way that `NewOrder` can be a header list instead of indexes?

Comment: @shepherd you can index a MATLAB table using cell arrays of header/footer names. e.g. `other_new_t = t({'e', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd'}, {'e', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd'})`

Answer (score 5):

Let the table be defined as

```
T = table;
T.a = [1 3 1 4 6].';
T.b = [2 5 3 4 7].';
T.c = [3 7 4 1 2].';
T.d = [4 2 6 7 1].';
T.e = [5 6 1 8 6].';
```

And let the new desired order be

```
order = {'e' 'b' 'c' 'a' 'd'};
```

The table can be reordered using just indexing:

```
[~, ind] = ismember(order, T.Properties.VariableNames);
T_reordered = T(ind,order);
```

Note that:

- To reorder only columns you'd use `T_reorderedCols = T(:,order);`
- To reorder only rows you'd use `T_reorderedRows = T(ind,:);`

So in this example,

```
T = 

    a    b    c    d    e
    _    _    _    _    _

    1    2    3    4    5
    3    5    7    2    6
    1    3    4    6    1
    4    4    1    7    8
    6    7    2    1    6

T_reordered = 

    e    b    c    a    d
    _    _    _    _    _

    6    7    2    6    1
    6    5    7    3    2
    1    3    4    1    6
    5    2    3    1    4
    8    4    1    4    7
```

Comment: but there is headers for rows as well.

Comment: I really like this implementation, nice use of `ismember` and the table's properties.

Comment: Yep very nice @LuisMendo I learned something (yet again) thanks!

Comment: It's refreshing to see an answer you wrote that's longer than 20 bytes ;) This is precisely what I was looking for, in particular the "columns only" comment.

Comment: @Giuseppe :-) Funny thing is, I have never used `table`s in my normal Matlab code