# Matlab sort a table using an external vector

Tags: matlab, sorting, vector, external

Does exist a way to sort a table A according to the order that the elements of one of its columns, let's say X, have in column Y of another table B? Y and X are the same vector but are ordered differently in the two tables A and B. I want to use Y order to sort table A.

Comment: can you provide an example of input and desired output?

Comment: Do you really mean a [`table`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html), or just a numeric 2D array (matrix)?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes I really mean a table

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607137/reorder-table-rows-and-columns-matlab/29607338#29607338) question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second output of [`ismember`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) tells you the desired sorting, which you can then use as row index into your table:

```
[~, ind] = ismember(B.Y, A.X); %// Or ismember(A.X, B.Y), depending on what you want
X_sorted = X(ind,:);
```